# How do i make this fluid player auto pause after its done playing

Tags: javascript

I will like to make the fluid player auto pause after each video is done playing

`<script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v3/current/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>

<video id="video-id"><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

<script>

```
var myFP = fluidPlayer(

    'video-id', {

"layoutControls": {

    "controlBar": {

        "autoHideTimeout": 3,

        "animated": true,

        "autoHide": true

    },

    "htmlOnPauseBlock": {

        "html": null,

        "height": null,

        "width": null

    },

    "autoPlay": true,
```

"mute": true,

```
    "allowTheatre": true,

    "playPauseAnimation": true,

    "playbackRateEnabled": true,

    "allowDownload": false,

            "loop": true,

    "playButtonShowing": true,

    "fillToContainer": true,

    "posterImage": ""

},

"vastOptions": {

    "adList": \[

        {

            "roll": "preRoll",

            "vastTag": "https://www.videosprofitnetwork.com/watch.xml?key=ddbbe516ba5a32d04f608af9bb011c1a",

            "adText": ""

        }

    \],

    "adCTAText": false,

    "adCTATextPosition": ""

}
```

});

</script></source></video>`u

Comment: Hi David and welcome to SO. *Stack over flow it won't be difficult if u just make the form be a* what does this mean? What is the current behavior and how does it differ from the expected result? Have you consulted the documentation of FluidPlayer and found any leads to solve your issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you check the documentation you have multiple events available that you can hook to, to perform whatever action you desire

https://docs.fluidplayer.com/docs/api/events/

in your example it could look somehting like this

```
myFP.on('ended', function(){ myFP.pause();});
```